# Sqlite3 in python program

Tags: python, sqlite

```
(name,description, price, is_private)VALUES(?,?,?,?)", data )
```

It shows error in VALUES as invalid syntax and i have no idea why is that . Anyone knows?

firstly ive faced an issuse in the table name part and now in the values syntax

Comment: provide               a [mre]

Comment: Is this the whole query? Can you provide the whole line along with content of `data`? Provide the error as well

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.